# Specifying order in which elements break

Tags: html, css

I have three inline-block elements side-by-side, with the middle element containing inline-block elements also. When there is not enough room to render side-by-side, the outer elements will break, creating three rows.

Is it possible to specify that the breaks occur between child elements of #block2 before they occur between #block1, #block2 and #block3?

### Html

```
<div id="block1"></div>
<ul id="block2">
    <li></li> <!-- I'd like these to break first -->
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<div id="block3"></div>
```

### Css

```
#block1, #block3 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
#block2 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#block2 li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LGXht/1/

Comment: An attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/LGXht/4/ but it doesn't break nicely

Comment: I think I solved my own problem. http://jsfiddle.net/LGXht/5/. It doesn't behave very nicely when it gets really small, but that can be solved with some media queries.

Comment: I didn't get your question, read it wrong: I thought you wanted 2 above 1 and 3. My fiddle answers another question...